# GCD of two numbers $4a^2 + 3,4ab-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, gcd-and-lcm

I came across this problem while solving some contest math. Please help me out with this.

What are all the possible GCD for two numbers of the form $4a^2 + 3,4ab-1$?

Comment: What have you tried?  Writing out examples might give you a sense of the possibilities.

Comment: I tried 9 sets of numbers each having residue class mod 3

Comment: try to use euclidean algorithm.

Comment: I tried. The only gcd I could get was 1. I wanted to know if there was any other.

Comment: If $a=1,b=2$ both terms are $7$.

Comment: If $d$ divides both, $d$ must divide $$b(4a^2+3)-a(4ab-1)=a+3b$$

 and $$4b(a+3b)-(4ab-1)=1+12b^2$$

Comment: Okay, are there any other solutions (apart from 1 and 7)

Comment: As I say, I'd try a lot of examples ($(1,2)$ didn't take very long to find),

Comment: I see. Is there any other way to obtain concrete solutions without trying examples?

Answer (score 2):

We show below that there are infinitely many primes which can divide the gcd.
We also characterize all of them.

**Claim 1:** If $p$ is any prime
$$p|gcd( 4a^2 + 3,4ab-1) .$$
then $p \neq 2,3$.

**Proof** $4a^2 + 3$ is odd hence $p \neq 2$.

Assume by contradiction that $p=3$. Then $3|4a^2 + 3 \Rightarrow 3|a \Rightarrow 3|4ab \Rightarrow 3 \nmid 4ab-1$.

**Claim 2:** If $p\neq 3$ any odd prime such that $-3$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$, then there exists $a,b$ such that 
$$p|gcd( 4a^2 + 3,4ab-1) .$$

Note that Legendre symbol immediately tells you what the prime needs to be modulo 12.

Proof of **claim 1.**

The equation 
$$ 4a^2 + 3 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$
has solutions.

Pick one such $a$, and then the equation 
$$3b=-a \pmod{p}$$
has solutions. Pick such $b$.

Then 
$$4a^2\equiv -3 \pmod{p}$$
and 
$$12ab \equiv 4a (3b) \equiv -4a^2 \equiv 3 \pmod{p}$$
which yields 
$$4ab \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$$

**Claim 3:** If $p$ is any prime
$$p|gcd( 4a^2 + 3,4ab-1) .$$
then $-3$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod{p}$.

**Proof**
$$p |gcd( 4a^2 + 3,4ab-1)  \Rightarrow p|4a^2+3 \Rightarrow \\
-3=(2a)^2 \pmod{p}$$

**Conclusion** Let $p$ be a prime. Then there exists $a,b$ such that $p|gcd( 4a^2 + 3,4ab-1)$ **if and only if** $p \neq 2,3$ and 
$$ \left(\frac{-3}{p} \right)=1$$
**if and only if** $$p\equiv 1,7 \pmod{12}$$